# Excel - Delete current row and row above based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, cell, rows

Each week I receive a spreadsheet that can contain up to 4,000 rows.  If any date is in Column C, I need to delete that row and the row above it.  Can someone help me with some VBA code that I can run on each new file which I get each week.  It's a pain to go through 4,000+ rows of data by hand each week.

In the screenshot, I would be deleting rows 157, 158, 159 and 160.
[image: Screenshot showing rows to be deleted]

Much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Give this short macro a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v As Variant

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "C").Value
        If v <> "" Then
            If IsDate(v) Then
                Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i - 1, "C")).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you have two or more sequential cells with dates like:

[image]

then this code should be used:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v As Variant
    Dim rKill As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rKill = Nothing
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "C").Value
        If v <> "" Then
            If IsDate(v) Then
                If rKill Is Nothing Then
                    Set rKill = Cells(i, "C")
                    Set rKill = Union(rKill, Cells(i - 1, "C"))
                Else
                    Set rKill = Union(rKill, Cells(i, "C"))
                    Set rKill = Union(rKill, Cells(i - 1, "C"))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If rKill Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    rKill.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

*(this will insure that all the "x" rows also get deleted.)*

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Steve  See my **EDIT#1**